# find a piece of a string in a list and replace

Tags: python, list

I've come across posts that demonstrate how to find a string in a list and replace, but i'm having difficulty generalizing the search to only a piece of a string.

For example

```
listX = ['color green', 'shape circle', 'above t']
```

I'd like to find all strings that begin with 'above', i've been able to do some minimal searching of a list using `any` and leaving the following space `'above '` but I can't figure out how to replace what I find.

Output i'm trying to create would be:

```
['color green', 'shape circle', 'above']
```

I'd also like to figure out how to remove a string that begins with 'above' from the list all together.

Comment: `new_list = [item if not item.startswith('above') else 'above' for item in listX]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
['above' if x.startswith('above') else x for x in listX]
```

If you would like to remove all strings that start with `'above'` then you can do something like what @JonClements mentioned in comments:

```
[x for x in listX if not x.startswith('above')]
```

Alternatively:

```
from itertools import filterfalse
list(filterfalse(lambda x: x.startswith('above'), listX))
```

Comment: I prefer my unnecessarily complicated logic :P

Comment: @roganjosh Sorry for collision: it's basically the same answer.

Comment: No collision. If I wanted to answer, I would have. I was also being sarcastic, you have my upvote :) For some reason, my first thought was a backwards approach

Comment: and the second part of the OP's Q would be then `[x for x in listX if not x.startswith('above')]` I guess

Comment: Thanks much, is removing it from the list a simple tweak of this?

Comment: @JonClements Oh, I did not notice the last question after having to read the first part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this worked for me, it printed:

['color green', 'shape circle', 'whatever you want']

```
listX = ['color green', 'shape circle', 'above t']

for i in range(len(listX)):

    splitting = listX[i].split(' ')
    if splitting[0] == 'above':
        listX[i] = 'whatever you want'

print(listX)
```

Comment: `.startswith()` is a much cleaner approach IMO but yes, this would work

Comment: This could help me figure out something else i'm working on. Would `splitting[1]` return 't', in this case?

Comment: @yodish yes, it splits on whitespace and gives a list

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(listX):
    if item.startswith('above'):
        listX[idx] = 'above'
```

After that, we will have one or more `'above'`s, then we can remove them all.

```
while listX.count('above') > 0:
    listX.remove('above')
```

Comment: This is not bad for the first part of the question: modifying the list in place.